# Android "CameraDevice 0 died unexpectedly" after long exposure

Tags: android, android-camera

I am building an app that captures images and need to sometimes expose for up to 2 seconds. However, when I take a picture with the exposure over 1600ms I receive the error "W/CameraDevice-JV-0: CameraDevice 0 died unexpectedly", the current activity closes and the last activity resumes. The weird thing is that this doesn't happen until after the captured image is displayed on screen, processed, and saved. This is using the camera2 api on a Nexus 6P running the Android O preview.

Edit:
After doing some digging and testing with other devices all devices appear to have some sort of max exposure time. I tested with a Nexus 5 and a Galaxy S6. Both of these devices would not expose past their max exposure times no matter what number you gave it. The Nexus 6P on the other hand will. The 6P's max exposure appears to be 234.324552ms. However, if you give it a time of 1000ms it will report that it exposed that long and the image will be brighter than at 234 ms. I am not sure if this is associated with the soft crashes I am experiencing because the crashes don't happen until the exposure is above 1600ms, not the 234ms limit.

Comment: Have you checked the LogCat for a specific error?

Comment: Yes that is exactly where I got it from, it is a one line warning, nothing above or below it.